# jQuery deferred exception - Storing API attribute with hyphen in object

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, object, syntax

Have submitted an ajax API call to musicbrainz API. I am receiving their returned data in JSON format which is expected response. As I parse through the returned data, I want to extract two attributes labeled life-span.begin and life-span.end

One of the returned JSON attributes is life-span. When I try to pull that data into my own obj using this js code:

```
    var artistName = results.artists[0].name

    artistObj = {
        // artist: results.artists[0].name,
        activeFrom: results.artists[0].life-span.begin,
        activeTill: results.artists[0].life-span.end,
    }
    console.log(results);
    // console.log(artistName);
});

console.log(artistObj);
```

I receive an error in devtools on Chrome that the span is causing issues. I've tried wrapping it in ["life-span"] but the syntax doesn't appear to be correct for the obj format. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Returned data JSON from API call:

```
0:
  country: "US"
  disambiguation: "90s US grunge band"
  life-span:
    begin: "1988-01"
    end: "1994-04-05"
    ended: true
  name: "Nirvana"
```

Comment: Can you include a small sample of the returned data?

Comment: Thanks vmank. Updated question with a section of returned data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the API and I successfully retrieved the `life-span`. Have you tried this `results.artists[0]['life-span']['end']`?

Comment: That solve does work. I think placing additional "."'s in the code was what was messing me up. Thank you for the quick assistance!

Comment: @JonDeavers actually the problem was that you have used ```-``` in an object member name, not the ```.```

Comment: Thanks Lajos. That's where my issue originated but I did not create the key name, that was what was returned from a third party API. I was trying to get the key pulled into my local object. vmark's solution solved that for me.